# How to limit number of records in Django Rest Framework reverse relations

Tags: json, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am getting started with Django Rest Framework, and it's behaving quite well. I got all the stuff working as I wanted it to be. I have came across a problem that I am not getting answer of.

I am using reverse relationship.

### Models

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)

class Picture(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField("Title", max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    pro = models.ForeignKey(Province, verbose_name="Province")
```

When I write the reverse relationship serializers of Province, e.g. for a single province.

### Views

```
ProToPicturesSerial(node, many=False).data
```

I get all the `pictures` in this province. I want to get some number of pictures, maybe last 3, or the 5 pictures that are added lately.

How can I limit the number of picture instance? Because as the number grows in the picture records, the application will tend to get slower.

### Serializer

```
class ProToPicturesSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pro_pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'intro', 'description', 'pro_pictures')
```

Let me know if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can point the `source` attribute of `PictureSerializer` to a method on province that returns only 3 related pics:

```
class ProToPicturesSerial(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pro_pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True, source='first_three_pics')

    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'intro', 'description', 'pro_pictures')
```

and

```
class Province(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)

    def first_three_pics(self):
        return self.picture_set.all()[:3]
```

Comment: But what is the basis of the order of the first three pics? The Primary key? If so is it automatically ascending or descending?

Comment: @BilliAm you can use order_by on the query to control items order, e.g. self.picture_set.all().order_by('-created_date')[:3] or use model Meta ordering attribute.... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by